# How can I calculate the Kolmogorov-Smirnov Tests (ks.test) with raster data in R?

Tags: raster, r, geotiff-tiff

I want to test if my data (especially the temperatures of the landsurface) are normal distributed.

```
ks.test(rasterstack[],"pnorm",alternative="two.sided",exact=NULL)
```

This is the result:

One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  r_vector
D = 0.086658, p-value = 0.4405
alternative hypothesis: two-sided

Is this the right code to test raster with a ks.test?

Comment: Added the R tag so people who look for stuff with the R tag will find this.

Comment: Please read the primary literature on this test, its assumptions (eg., cumulative distribution function to facilitate step test) and most importantly, the Gaussian characteristics associated with the rule of large numbers. This is something that is oft neglected with statistical analysis of raster data. It is best to think of a raster as a population and take a sample for statistical analysis. With rasters you inevitability have enough observations that they assume Gaussian distributional characteristics. As such, without using a sample,  I would question distributional equality tests.

Answer (score 3):

Run a little test. Make a 10x10 random raster:

```
> r1 = raster(matrix(rnorm(100),10,10))
```

Feed to `ks.test`:

```
> ks.test(r1,"pnorm",alternative="two.sided",exact=NULL)

    One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  r1
D = 0.052428, p-value = 0.9463
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

Now normally you'd feed `ks.test` a numeric vector of data values. You can turn a raster to a numeric vector of data values by various means, I usually stick `[]` after the raster to subset all the values:

```
> ks.test(r1[],"pnorm",alternative="two.sided",exact=NULL)

    One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  r1[]
D = 0.052428, p-value = 0.9463
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

Now that looks identical to running it on the raster.

Running on a raster stack instead of a single-band raster gives an error:

```
> ks.test(stack(r1,r1),"pnorm",alternative="two.sided",exact=NULL)
Error in x[!is.na(x)] : object of type 'S4' is not subsettable
```

so I don't know what your `rasterstack` object is.

Comment: Thanks! I edited my post and tried another way (see on top). But i do not know, if i have really calculated the temperatures of all rasterlayers?

Comment: Make some tiny test rasters and stacks from random numbers - 3x3 is probably enough, 10x10 definitely - then try `ks.test` as you do, then convert the values into the raster to a simple vector and try again. If you get the same result - like I do above - then you *must* be using all the values in all the layers. Use `c(rasterstack[])` to get all the values in a stack - you can verify that with tiny test data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  tried your alternative. Now i get this Warning:
In ks.test(stacked_raster_values, "pnorm", alternative = "two.sided", :
  for the Komogorov-Smirnov test there should be no bindings

Comment: Which alternative? Please edit your question and show the structure of your data and the code you used with the error message.